# Ignore only files in root directory via Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

I have a pretty simple ASP.NET MVC application directory structure, a sample as follows:

```
root/
----- views/
---------- index.cshtml
---------- web.config
----- scripts/
---------- main.js
---------- plugin.js
----- web.config
```

Given this directory structure, I have a small Powershell script that copies everything in the `[sourceDir]`, ignores a few files, and copies it to `[targetDir]`.

I'm having an issue with the first step that copies everything in the `[sourceDir]` using the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet. Here is my sample script (edited for brevity):

```
Get-ChildItem [sourceDir] -Recurse -Exclude web.config | Copy-Item -Destination [targetDir]
```

The problem is that the `-Exclude` parameter excludes the web.config in the root AND the web.config in the views directory. Technically, it ignores every web.config; however, I just want to ignore the file in the root.

Is it possible to ignore only the web.config in the root via `Get-ChildItem`? If not, which cmdlet should I use?

## Solution

As suggested, abandoning the -Exclude parameter for a Where Linq clause was the correct solution. I actually had an array of files to ignore, so I used the `-NotIn` operator instead of the `-NotMatch`, sample script:

```
Get-ChildItem [sourceDir] -Recurse | 
     Where { $_.FullName -NotIn $_filesToIgnore } |
     Copy-Item -Destination [targetDir]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-Exclude` parameter on Get-ChildItem has been a notorious source of problems.  Try it this way:

```
Get-ChildItem [sourceDir] | 
    Where {$_.FullName -notmatch "$sourceDirVar\\web\.config"} | 
    Copy-Item -Destination [targetDir] -Recurse
```

Comment: Perfect. My Linq-in-Powershell-fu is weak, but this is exactly what I needed. Technically, i had an array of files to ignore, so I substituted -NotMatch with -NotIn.